# Excel VBA Run Time Error '424' object required

Tags: vba, excel

I am totally new in VBA and coding in general, am trying to get data from cells from the same workbook (get framework path ...) and then to start application (QTP) and run tests.

I am getting this error when trying to get values entered in excel cells:

```
Run Time Error '424' object required
```

I believe I am missing some basic rules but I appreciate your help.  Please see below the part of code in question:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RunTest_Click()

    Dim envFrmwrkPath As Range
    Dim ApplicationName As Range
    Dim TestIterationName As Range
    'Dim wb As Workbook
    'Dim Batch1 As Worksheets
    Dim objEnvVarXML, objfso, app As Object
    Dim i, Msgarea

    Set envFrmwrkPath = ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value ' error displayed here
    Set ApplicationName = ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value
    Set TestIterationName = ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value
```

Answer (score 29):

The first code line, `Option Explicit` means (in simple terms) that all of your variables have to be **explicitly declared** by `Dim` statements. They can be any type, including object, integer, string, or even a variant.

This line: `Dim envFrmwrkPath As Range` is declaring the variable `envFrmwrkPath` of type `Range`.  This means that you can only set it to a range.

This line: `Set envFrmwrkPath = ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value` is attempting to set the `Range` type variable to a specific Value that is in cell `D6`.  This could be a integer or a string for example (depends on what you have in that cell) but it's not a range.

I'm assuming you want the value stored in a variable. Try something like this:

```
Dim MyVariableName As Integer
MyVariableName = ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value
```

This assumes you have a number (like 5) in cell D6.  Now your variable will have the value.

For simplicity sake of learning, you can remove or comment out the `Option Explicit` line and VBA will try to determine the type of variables at run time.

---

Try this to get through this part of your code

```
Dim envFrmwrkPath As String
Dim ApplicationName As String
Dim TestIterationName As String
```

Comment: Really thank you for your quick reply,

i posted my question after trying all ways i found: Used/Unused Option Explicit ...tried other expressions; now by using your suggestion; am getting: Run Time Error '13' type mismatch ...

well, envFrmwrkPath is a path to the QTP framework entered in the excel cell by the user; i want to get this path then get other reusable files/folders...

i will add my excel my file if this could help...

Comment: If the cell contains a "path" it will actually be treated like a String.  Adding the file will be helpful.  Just edit your original question and include a link to your file.

Comment: yes i tried with String  and was ok, getting other errors dealing with QTP now. Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the `.value` from your code.

```
Set envFrmwrkPath = ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value
```

instead of this, use:

```
Set envFrmwrkPath = ActiveSheet.Range("D6")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options,

-If you want the value:

```
Dim MyValue as Variant ' or string/date/long/...
MyValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

-if you want the cell object:

```
Dim oCell as Range  ' or object (but then you'll miss out on intellisense), and both can also contain more than one cell.
Set oCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Workbooks("Textfile_Receiving").Sheets("menu").Range("g1").Value = PROV.Text
    Workbooks("Textfile_Receiving").Sheets("menu").Range("g2").Value = MUN.Text
    Workbooks("Textfile_Receiving").Sheets("menu").Range("g3").Value = CAT.Text
    Workbooks("Textfile_Receiving").Sheets("menu").Range("g4").Value = Label5.Caption

    Me.Hide

    Run "filename"

End Sub

Private Sub MUN_Change()
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 2

    While Range("m" & CStr(r)).Value <> ""
        If Range("m" & CStr(r)).Value = MUN.Text Then
        Label5.Caption = Range("n" & CStr(r)).Value
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Wend

End Sub

Private Sub PROV_Change()
    If PROV.Text = "LAGUNA" Then
        MUN.Text = ""
        MUN.RowSource = "Menu!M26:M56"
    ElseIf PROV.Text = "CAVITE" Then
        MUN.Text = ""
        MUN.RowSource = "Menu!M2:M25"
    ElseIf PROV.Text = "QUEZON" Then
        MUN.Text = ""
        MUN.RowSource = "Menu!M57:M97"
    End If
End Sub
```