# Code throws an error when a breakpoint is added but not otherwise

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in a file like:

```
TIME|DIRECTION|ORDERID|SYMBOL|ROUTE||QUANTITY|PRICE
2012-05-29 11:17:18|B|1337|ZNGA|ARCA||6500|5.48
2012-05-29 11:17:53|B|1389|AAPL|ARCA||200|569.85
2012-05-29 11:18:22|S|1970|BRK/B|ARCA||600|77.48
2012-05-29 11:18:24|B|2335|BRK/B|ARCA||600|79.3
2012-05-29 11:19:27|B|2416|ZNGA|ARCA||4000|6.08
2012-05-29 11:19:29|S|2997|LNKD|ARCA||500|91.27
2012-05-29 11:19:40|S|3078|ZNGA|ARCA||3900|6.04
```

I am trying to write VBA code which will consume the data and return statistics based on ticker (cumulative quantity, price, etc.). I have written code using a dictionary object with a class object. This is for an assignment, so I have to do it that way.

If I just run the code, it compiles just fine. The numbers are incorrect (trying to fix that), but the code compiles.

When I add a breakpoint and try to step into the code, it started to do funny things. It ran fine for the first few runs, but it started breaking when I stopped runs/added things etc. If I step into the code, it seems to think that a dictionary object exists when it. So the statement `If Not trades.exists(ticker) Then` evaluates as `False`. Then it breaks on the line `trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal - lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)` when it presumably tries to search for a value but finds none.

> The error is: Run-time error '424': Object Required.

Oddly, again, if I run it without the breakpoint it complies just fine.

```
Sub defineVar()
myFile = Range("$A$2")
End Sub

Public Sub test_everything()

Call defineVar

'Dim line As trade
Dim lines As Collection
Set lines = New Collection

Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, file_line
    lines.Add file_line
Loop
Close #1


Dim posTime As Byte
Dim posDirection As Byte
Dim posSymbol As Byte
Dim posQuantity As Byte
Dim posPrice As Byte

posTime = getColPosByHeader("TIME", lines(1))
posDirection = getColPosByHeader("DIRECTION", lines(1))
posSymbol = getColPosByHeader("SYMBOL", lines(1))
posQuantity = getColPosByHeader("QUANTITY", lines(1))
posPrice = getColPosByHeader("PRICE", lines(1))

Dim pos As Long
Dim ticker As String

Dim trades As Scripting.Dictionary
Set trades = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim trade As Stock
Set trade = New Stock

pos = 2

While pos <= lines.Count
    lineItems = Split(lines(pos), "|")
    ticker = lineItems(posSymbol)
    If Not trades.exists(ticker) Then
        trade.symbol = ticker
        trade.cashVal = 0
        trade.positionVal = lineItems(posQuantity)
        trade.endPriceVal = lineItems(posPrice)
        trade.maxDateVal = lineItems(posTime)
        trades.Add trade.symbol, trade
        If InStr(1, lineItems(posDirection), "B") Then
            trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal - lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        Else: trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal + lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        End If
    Else:
    If InStr(1, lineItems(posDirection), "B") Then
        trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal - lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        trades(ticker).positionVal = trades(ticker).positionVal + lineItems(posQuantity)
            If lineItems(posTime) >= trades(ticker).maxDateVal Then
                trades(ticker).maxDateVal = lineItems(posTime)
                trades(ticker).endPriceVal = lineItems(posPrice)
                End If
    Else: trades(ticker).cashVal = trades(ticker).cashVal + lineItems(posQuantity) * lineItems(posPrice)
        trades(ticker).positionVal = trades(ticker).positionVal - lineItems(posQuantity)
        If lineItems(posTime) >= trades(ticker).maxDateVal Then
            trades(ticker).maxDateVal = lineItems(posTime)
            trades(ticker).endPriceVal = lineItems(posPrice)
        End If
    End If
    End If
    Debug.Print trades(ticker).positionVal
    pos = pos + 1
Wend

Dim k As Variant
For Each k In trades.Keys
    Debug.Print k, trades(k).cashVal, trades(k).positionVal, trades(k).endPriceVal, trades(k).maxDateVal
Next

End Sub
```

Edited to Add: 
This is what my class objects look like:

```
'Class Module: Stock
Public symbol As String
Public cashVal As Double
Public positionVal As Double
Public endPriceVal As Double
Public maxDateVal As Date
```

Does anyone know how to cure this curious problem?

Comment: this is a post where talk about error 424: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358540/excel-vba-run-time-error-424-object-required

Comment: If your indentation is where you think the `If` and `Else` statements match up, you should run this through [an indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation). That said, I don't understand what the dictionary is even *for* - you're re-using the same `Stock` object, so you end up with a single object in the dictionary under each different key.

Comment: The idea is that each stock (FB, AAPL, etc) is a different key and returns each statistic for it. The number of unique stocks is unknown in the file. That's what I was trying to build, anyway, but there are bugs. Unfortunately I am having trouble debugging because the code won't compile if I add a breakpoint...

If you have suggestions about my other issue though, I will gladly listen!

Comment: Won't compile, or is throwing a run-time error 424? Those are two completely different things. Can you edit the question to include the code for the `Stock` class?

Comment: Seems like Power Query might be more appropriate to use, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve. It has `extract, transform, load` capabilities, so it can take structured/delimited data as input, which you can then transform into a table and load to an Excel sheet.

Comment: Comintern, it is throwing the run-time error 424. No error gets thrown if I run the code without the breakpoint. I edited the question to include the code for the stock class!