# How Excel VBA to make ticker in url for data scraping

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Per previous case, I tried avoid ticker in url by adding an variable from `.querySelector("#autocomplete_input").value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET1").Cells(1, 1).` It's go to annual financials well but not success into quarter financials`.querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/" &.querySelector("#autocomplete_input").value &"/financials/income/quarter']")`. It doesn’t work Is there any way I can use it, thanks?

```
Public Sub makeselections()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

With ie
 .Visible = True
 .Navigate2 "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials"

While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
With .document
.querySelector("#autocomplete_input").value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET1").Cells(1, 1)
.querySelector("#investing_ac_button").Click
End With

While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Dim ele As Object
 With .document
  Do
  Set ele = .querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/" &.querySelector("#autocomplete_input").value &"/financials/income/quarter']")
  On Error Resume Next
  Loop While ele Is Nothing
.querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/" &.querySelector("#autocomplete_input").value &"/financials/income/quarter']").Selected = True
.querySelector(".financials select").FireEvent "onchange"

  stop
 End With
 .Quit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358540/excel-vba-run-time-error-424-object-required/21358738

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Run Time Error '424' object required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358540/excel-vba-run-time-error-424-object-required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are working with lowercase tickers. Consider also using a timed loop as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494738/6241235) SO answer.

```
Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, var As String

    var = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document
            .querySelector("#autocomplete_input").Value = var
            .querySelector("#investing_ac_button").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim ele As Object
        With .document
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .querySelector("[value^='/investing/stock/" & LCase$(var) & "/financials/income/quarter']")
                On Error GoTo 0
            Loop While ele Is Nothing
            ele.Selected = True
            .querySelector(".financials select").FireEvent "onchange"

            Stop
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks QHarr very much. I couldn't get it for many hours. You solved it just a few minutes. Appreciate it again.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I try your code again today. It’s strange to stay running VBA all time time but never stopped. Can you help guide me, thanks?

Comment: Is it running? Did your remove the _Stop_ keyword?

Comment: Yes, I removed stop and Run VBA. It’s always running and never stop. The web doesn’t change to quarter financials.

Comment: Unsure as it runs perfectly for me. You may need to open a new question and explain what has changed but be aware that it may get downvoted if people can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi QHarr, 'on error goto 0' seems like stuck the programming when I esc it in duration. I also tried with specific tiger instead of &Lcase(var)& and sometime it works but not all the time. I'll open a ticket for optimization if something I can learn, thanks.

Comment: Hi QHarr, Thanks for your comments. I’ll ask optimization question for it if someone or you have a great idea.

Comment: Ah so it is stuck in the loop because it is not a timed loop. So firstly it needs to be adapted to a timed loop as per my linked answer I gave at the top of my answer.

Comment: Which makes sense as if you have a ticker not found then ele will always be Nothing so yes you need a form of timed loop that  moves you out of the loop after a max number of seconds.